# How to join a Minecraft Server on Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console

I know there are Minecraft servers on PC right? There are lots of stuff I wanted to try out on the servers but the problem is I'm on Xbox not PC. Are there any servers on Xbox? If so, how can I join them? Please I'm just a normal player and I don't know really everything about the game.

Answer (score 1):

I believe servers on Xbox 360 and PlayStation do not exist. You can add someone via Xbox live and they can invite you to they're single player world though.

Hope I helped.